# Hide Only Modules Tab Menu in odoo

Tags: python, xml, menu, module, odoo

How do I hide just the Module Tab Menu in odoo?
I want to make a module which module hides this Module Tab Menu in odoo.

ODOO Menu :

Modules

- Local Modules
- Installed Modules
- Update Module List
- Apply Scheduled Upgrades
- Apps

I want to hide this menu.

Comment: Do you want to hide setting menu?

Comment: No just the module menu as i describe in my question.

Comment: it is only visible to group Module Features. if you want to hide the menu from non admin user you can remove user from the group.

Answer (score 1):

To hide a menu, you have to assign access rights group to it. You can do it via custom module, overriding that menu or assigning it through menu management (in Odoo). To do it via module, can do something like this (in appropriate xml):

```
<menuitem id="base.menu_management" name="Modules" parent="menu_administration" sequence="0" groups="some_group"/>
```

Doing this, menu will be visible to users that have that group only. There is no "hide" feature to hide menu for the sake of hiding. But using groups can be accomplish same thing.

Also it is possible to force delete menu if you for some reason don't need it. For example:

```
<delete id="base.menu_management" model="ir.ui.menu"/>
```

But keep in mind that deleting menu can lead to errors if any other menu uses it as parent. Also Odoo will throw warning that such external ID was not found when you upgrade base module (but it will work anyway).

Comment: Thank you Andrius but i don't want to show this module menu for some reasons and I don't want to delete this menu, I just want to Hide Module Menu via my custom module and when i want that Module Menu then i'm just uninstall my custom module and Module Menu is shown.

Comment: Well it possible to rewrite settings menu. But that is lot of work and for such small thing, I don't think it is practical. What I mean, you can override all menus except `module` menu. Also if you specify to delete it, it will delete menu, but when you remove your module and upgrade base module, `menu` will appear again. So actually it won't be removed permanently.